# Delay after a subsite is created

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-online

I'm stuck after creating a new subsite programmticly.

I have created an remote event receiver after a employe is added a new subsite is created under /sites/employes/.

That works fine but after the subsite is created i want to add an item to a list i have added to my template file.

The problem is when my code fires the subsite is not yet created. When i add a pause it works but i'm looking for another solution because the pause
isn't working 100%

Code

```
var token = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(SHAREPOINT_PID, parentSite.Authority, null).AccessToken;

using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(parentSite.ToString(), token)) {
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    WebTemplateCollection templates = web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1043, true);
    clientContext.Load(templates);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (WebTemplate wt in templates){
        if (wt.Title == contentTypeString){
            webTemplateName = wt.Name;
            //we found the template we were looking for, stop looking through the rest of the templates
            break;
        }
    }

    string webTemplateName = "STS#0";
    Web newWeb = null;
    WebCreationInformation wcInfo = null;

    wcInfo = new WebCreationInformation();
    wcInfo.Url = nameSubSite;
    wcInfo.Title = employeName
    wcInfo.Description = "Employe";

    wcInfo.Language = 1043;
    wcInfo.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = true;
    wcInfo.WebTemplate = webTemplateName;

    newWeb = web.Webs.Add(wcInfo);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    clientContext.Load(newWeb, w => w.Title);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```